# retrieving data from sql server to excel dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

**i have one column named rollno and another column NAME  , i have data in Rollno column 
i need to fetch the names according to roll numbers from sql server  dynamically   .**

Comment: you can add name according to roll number by reading column value and using where column value is equal to you roll number value and corresponding value is set in name column

Comment: have you written any code?

Answer (score 0):

you could connect to SQL Server using **ADO**

[MSDN Library: ADO Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb) for **OLE DB Connection Strings**

then you could open an **ADO Recordset**

[MSDN Library: ADO Recordset  Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for **SQL**.

finally you could use the *CopyFromRecordset* method of the *Range* object in Excel to dump the data recordset into your worksheet:

[MSDN Library: CopyFromRecordset method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165427%28v=office.10%29.aspx)